# Highlight headings when link is active

Tags: html, css

Can this be done by css only? I want the H1 to be highlighted, when the ID1 link is active.

```
<a href=#id1>ID1</a>
<a href=#id1>ID2</a>
<h1 id="id1">This is the header</h1>
<h1 id="id2">This is the header</h1>
```

So if ID1 link is active, then H1 with id "id1" will be blue instead of red, ex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with :target

### The :target pseudo selector in CSS matches when the hash in the URL and the id of an element are the same.

```
<a href=#id1>ID1</a>
<a href=#id2>ID2</a>
<h1 id="id1">This is the header</h1>
<h1 id="id2">This is the header</h1>
```

and css

```
:target{
    color:red;

}
```

and [RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/g5QDp/4/)

Answer (score 2):

The above post is right with one more correction, as it works on hover.

use javascript to add CLASS="active to an element after click, lets say

```
h1.active{
   color:red;
   font-weight:bold
}
```

Html will have class="active" after click to the link

```
<a id=a1 href=#id1 onclick="javascript:getElementById('id1').className='active'">ID1</a>
<a id=a2 href=#id1 onclick="javascript:getElementById('id2').className='active'">ID2</a>
<h1 id="id1" class="">This is the header</h1>
<h1 id="id2" class="">This is the header</h1>
```

I hope this may help :)

Answer (score -1):

You could use the sibling selector (`~`) in combination with the `:active` state. As shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/5M8vV/).

```
#id1-ref:active ~ #id1 {
    color: #FF0000;
}

#id2-ref:active ~ #id2 {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

You do have to add extra ids to the anchor tags though.

#### Edit

Found a nice way of doing it with target. This might be better: http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/5M8vV/2/

```
h1:target {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

[Information on the `:target` selector.](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/)

Comment: @downvoter I would also like to know why I was downvoted with the other answer. Is it because you need multiple CSS selectors? Maybe your question isn't clear enough. Is my new method I edited into the post closer to what you need?